# Rhythm (sound change) detection on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

Sorry for my weak english

I've got some aif or MP3 tunes for plaing loud on the iPhone, 
and I need to do some 'sound change' detections,

such I would use for some visualisations (jumping man or other)

how to do it 'easy' on iPhone or how to do it 'fine'?

should I do fft or such, or something different?

I have seen some sound visualisations back then but all they
seem not to much good (they seem not to be much clear in reactions on
music change).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What are you currently using for playback? I would use audio queues or audio units - both give you access to buffers of audio samples as they're passed through to the hardware. At that point it's a matter of detecting peaks in the sound above a certain threshold, which you can do in a variety of different ways.

An FFT will not help you because you're interested in the time-domain waveform of the sound (its amplitude over time) not its frequency-domain characteristics (the relative strengths of different frequencies in different time windows.)

Comment: wouldnt FFT, done to, for example, 20 milisecond parts of audio, provided me more information about 'changes in sound' than simple amplitude (which i am afraid would b maybee not too much useful) ???

Comment: It will certainly provide more information about 'changes in sound' but is not useful if what you're interested in is changes in volume. If you want an animation every time there is a bass tone or something, an FFT would be great. But if you just want it whenever there's a 'hit' (bass, snare, whatever) then amplitude would be the way to go.

Comment: simple wav (aiff) amplitude without nothing with frequenzy will be usefull? I do not know but have doubts to it

Comment: It will be useful if you're interested in changes in volume, as in the percussion example I gave.